# Text fields in Chrome Extensions?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

So recently I have been getting into making Chrome Extensions. I want to add a text input field when a button is clicked, like this:

manifest:
    ...

```
"browser_action":{
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup":"popup.html"
},
"background":{
"scripts": ["background.js"]
},

"permissions":["tabs"]

}
```

background.js:

```
function textfield(){
var field = document.createElement("INPUT");
field.setAttribute("type","text");
field.setAttribute("value","Id:");
document.body.appendChild(field);
}
```

popup.html:
    ...

```
    <button onclick="textfield()"class="button"type="button">Regulations</button>
```

So the problem I am having is that I cannot figure out why the text field is appearing. The onclick does work, but it is not being generated for some reason.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code a little bit for extension to fire click event.

```js
document.getElementById('regButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var field = document.createElement('input'); // INPUT also works
  field.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  field.setAttribute('name', 'text');
  document.body.appendChild(field);
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="regButton" type="button">Regulations</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Extension doesn't allow inline functions. You need register the handler using `document.getElementById('elementId').addEventListener` inside your javascript.

<kbd>[Reference](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution)</kbd>